# changing the size of an array from a method in java

Tags: java, arrays

I have a 2D array and I want to make the size of the array the same as the number of appointments. The number of appointments is found in another class with this line

```
numOfAppointments = DB.numOfAppointmentsByUser(loggedInUserID);
```

And I declare the array at the top of the program so it is accessible from the whole program, this is that:

```
String[][] data = new String[numOfAppointments][2];
```

But I cant call the numOfAppointments above the data array because it isn't in a method and gives this error: 
`error: <identifier> expected` and if I call the numOfAppointment in a method then I will need to declare the data array in that method so that I can use the value from numOfAppointments as the size in the array.

How can I make it so that I can declare the array at the top of the program so it is accessible from all methods but at the same time call the numOfAppointments variable so that I can create the size of the array.

I have tried placing them both in a constructor like this:

```
numOfAppointments = DB.numOfAppointmentsByUser(loggedInUserID);

public String[][] data = new String[numOfAppointments][2];
```

I tried to make the array public in the constructor instead but it gives the error `illegal start of expression` and If I remove the `public` then the data array isn't accessible from any other method since it isn't public and is a child of that method. Thanks for any help.

Comment: What's the purpose of `static` word? :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to move the following declaration outside of the constructor to make it available globally!

```
public String[][] data;

public Constructor(...) {
    int numOfAppointments = DB.numOfAppointmentsByUser(loggedInUserID);

    data = new String[numOfAppointments][2];
}
```

Comment: wow that was so simple, been trying to solve it for ages. That did it, thanks a lot :)

Comment: a constructor should only assign values to member variables. It should not call methods in other classes and/or objects! Therefore the number of appointments should be passed as constructor parameter.